# How to correct a MySQL syntax error from Putty

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the following query in 'putty' for "mysql"

> mysql -user -password -e "select * from table_name" > '/tmp/output.txt'

but getting error as follows...

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -user-password -e "select * from table_name" > '/tmp/output.txt' at line 1

I need immediate help.

Comment: exactly what do you want to do with above query? Are you trying to run above query on mysql terminal or localhost terminal?

Comment: I am trying it in localhost terminal.. I want to send the output of a 'select' query to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on a windows server. The code below should work with no problems.

If this codes does not work then please post the exact code that you are using. Perhaps you are attempting a bad query.

```
mysql -uroot -p -e "select * from table_name" > "c:/tmp/output.txt"
```

Comment: I am using the same code posted in my que.. i.e.,

mysql -user -password -e "select * from table_name" > '/tmp/output.txt'

I even tries ur code but same error is repeated

Comment: try changing the single quote to double quote like I have above

Answer (score 0):

Try this command on localhost terminal to get output in a file from mysql table

```
mysql --user=mysql_username --password=mysql_password -e "select * into outfile '/tmp/output.txt' from database.table";
```

Comment: Its the same I posted in my que..

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -user-password -e "select * from table_name" > '/tmp/output.txt' at line 1

Comment: @Danny dear try above query.. mentioned in my answer that is `mysql --user=mysql_username --password=mysql_password -e "select * into outfile '/tmp/output.txt' from database.table";`

Comment: I tried but am getting the same error. :( 
I am not the root user for the database. May be that's the prblm. what do u think???

Comment: no that's not an issue. But above command is right tested by me on my mysql server.Strange why this is not working on your system?

Comment: what do u think are the possible reasons?

Comment: I even tried the following query.... but not able to get the desired output. I am getting the "access denied" error.

select * from table_name
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\SQL\output.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';


ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: @Danny Strange, problem is due to mysql database access permission for user. As in your query `''@'localhost'` this user has not access permission for your database and table. First of all you have to grant all access permission for the user.

Comment: Yes... I have used grant queries for the same but no use..
can u tell me the exact queries to be used

Comment: @Danny Go through the below link. Hope you will find out . http://tech2smooth.blogspot.in/2014/09/create-mysql-user-and-grant-permission.html

Comment: I cannot open that link right now. can u tell any other method

Comment: Syntax to create user:- `CREATE USER '< user name >'@'< password >' IDENTIFIED BY <PASSWORD>`
Syntax to grant permission:- `GRANT < permission > ON < database >.< table > WITH GRANT OPTION` After above query flush all PRIVILEGES  using `FLUSH PRIVILEGES `

Comment: can u be more specific about the 'GRANT' query... sorry to be crude.
I am using the below query but of no use...
grant all privileges on database.* to 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'password';

flush privileges;

Comment: LETS Your user is abc and you want to access database from anywhere and password is 123 and database is dump_db then query will be. `grant all privileges on dump_db.* to 'abc'@'%' identified by '123'`

Comment: Is there any mistake in my query that I sent in the before comment???

 grant all privileges on database.* to 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'password';

In my terminal, it is shown as 'danny@mysql'.. so I should use the same in 'grant' quert right??

Comment: USE THIS ONE `Grant ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;` then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES `